# Docker expose port unreachable

Tags: windows, docker

here is my docker command :

`docker run -p 8087:80 nginx:alpine`

But I can't access to

`http://localhost:8087`

Logs:

```
    $ docker run -p 8087:80 nginx:alpine
    /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to 
    perform configuration
    /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
    /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by- 
    default.sh
    10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of 
    /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in 
    /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on- 
    templates.sh
    /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

```
  This site is inaccessible localhost does not allow connection.
```

Have you an idea please about the solution ?

Comment: First of all drop `-d` , no use in detach mode (if you want to see what it happens, also you could do a `docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER` on you container

Comment: That runs perfectly for me. Please remove the `-d` and add the logs in your question.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: according to log it's working and and started the service. Please paste the error you are getting on web browser

Comment: This site is inaccessible localhost does not allow connection. ((On Windows))

Comment: Can you try with IP once

Comment: not an windows-docker expert, might want to check if firewall is blocking any ports

Comment: @RatishBansal with this IP ?   $ docker exec -t -i confident_pascal sh                                                                                                                                 / # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:0C
          inet addr:172.17.0.12  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0

Comment: it works with this IP ""docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com""

Answer (score 0):

If you are n Windows, don't type

```
http://localhost:8087
```

on your address bar, but type instead the IP address you see associated to your docker-machine.

You can find it out by typing on the command prompt

```
docker-machine ls
```